# object references an unsaved transient instance, Error only when trying to save with empty value

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an object EvalQuestionType with a one-to-many relationship to another object EvalSelectGroup. I save the relationship in a spring form like so:

```
<tr>
    <th><sf:label path="evalSelectGroup.id">Select Group</sf:label>
    <td><sf:select path="evalSelectGroup.id">
            <sf:option value="">None</sf:option>
            <sf:options items="${selectGroups}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" />
        </sf:select>        
    <br />
    <sf:errors path="evalSelectGroup.id" cssClass="error" /></td>
</tr>
```

It works fine if I select an option, but if I try to save with None selected (empty) I get the transient instance error. The value can be null (in the db and my hibernate mapping file). Is there a special way to format empty values in a Spring form select?

Spring 3.2.1
Hibernate 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best or right way to do it, but in the controller if I take the EvalQuestionType object passed by the form and set the evalSelectGroup object to null it works fine.

```
//if none selected in form
if(questionType.getEvalSelectGroup().getId() == null){
    questionType.setEvalSelectGroup(null);
}
```